How to enable mathbb export in org mode?
M-x org-latex-preview and html export work fine with the upper line, but not with the second line. I got no error, it's just displayed as is.
What am I missing?
\( {N} \)
\mathbb{N}

Mathjax (latest) is installed
Expected (and only provided by second line): ℕ

You need to put it into a math environment (and you'll also probably need the amssymb package - at least I did):
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{amssymb}

* math


\( {N} \)
\( \mathbb{N} \)


BTW, my Firefox does not seem to work with MathJax (?!?), but Google Chrome does.
